# How do I start with A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I have understanding of how to start a basic scene but, have NO clue on how to start coding within the browser as suggested in installation process.  Can you please kindly get back to me and tell me how I am able to edit my work on browser and see changes in real time?  Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the Getting Stared section in the docs:

https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/

Easiest way to start in browser is by remixing the [Glitch hello world](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe) as described in the link above.